# How to make Citrix session use only specified monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, citrix

I am using a 3 monitor configuration. Two panels side by side at the top and the laptop built-in under them. I would like my Citrix session to use the two monitors at the top only, so I can use my laptop Windows without having to switch back and forth. How do I achieve that?

All are on Windows 10.